# Why hovering a div element doesn't work on iOS Safari (iPhone/iPad)?

Tags: css, hover, mobile-safari

The code is very straight-forward, see part of it below. [Full example here](https://codepen.io/criscmaia/pen/yRrvaq):

**Plain HTML:**

```
<div class="test1">
  <div class="silver1">
    <span>test1</span>
  </div>
    <span>box 1</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}

.silver1 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.test1:hover .silver1 {
  top: 30px;
  left: 80px;
  border: 3px dotted blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Tests:**

- Hovering with a mouse in any popular browser in either Windows or
  Mac works fine.
- By tapping the boxes on an Android Mobile it works
  as well.
- Tapping on Safari (iPhone/iPad) nothing happens.
- Holding down on Safari sometimes work.

**Question**
How do I activate **:hover** for Safari iOS?
Ideally pure CSS solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try if with placing an :active after the :hover.

https://codepen.io/mausinc/pen/LgvmXv

```
.test1:hover:active .silver1 {
  top: 30px;
  left: 80px;
  border: 3px dotted blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Well "hover" isn't a thing on touch interfaces.

Chrome mobile tends to call the first tap, hover if it's specified and a subsequent tap the same as a click. This functionality can get strange for users too. Safari, as you discovered, ignores it completely.

I would suggest that you try really hard to remove any content from hovers that users MUST do to complete a process or navigate and replace them with interaction specific paradigms.

You may even want to test if the device is touch based and provide a completely different experience for those users instead of trying to match hover.

Here's a media query for touch devices. `@media (any-hover: none) { ... }`

More info from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/touch-devices-not-judged-size/) and a good [overview of what's possible in 2018](https://peterscene.com/detecting-touch-devices-2018-update/).